# Hooke's Law and the shape of coils

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, approximations

I've learned in school that the force in a coil is $F=kx$, linear on how much the coil is stretched. Two questions:

1. Is it always linear for every shape of a coil? Does it remain linear if we increase the radius of the coil, increase the length between loops and so on?
2. Can we deduce the value of $k$ based on the geometry of the coil?

The motivation is that I know how to deduce the inductance of a coil based on its shape, but I haven't seen that calculation done to deduce the $k$ in [Hooke's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law).

Comment: There is part of the discussion [here](http://tpt.aapt.org/resource/1/phteah/v33/i9/p566_s1?isAuthorized=no). Try to get the paper by alternative sources. I know the book Moyses Nussenzveig had a short treatment, but it isn't in English, afaik.You may search for the computation of elastic constants in [Continuum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics).

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22894/2451

Comment: Ah I answered that one :-) No upvote though :-( Ricbit, if question 22894 doesn't help maybe edit your question to indicate what's missing and I'll try to answer it here.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the wiki for Continuum Mechanics and the Springipedia solved my curiosity!
http://springipedia.com/compression-shape-sizes.asp