# Why do springs have helical shapes? Why do we not use a cylindrical rod as a spring?

Tags: spring

A spring is a mechanical flexible element and has to absorb energy from outside gradually. We are manufacturing springs in helical shapes on a large scale. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the shape (form; not cross-section) of a spring impact performance?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22894/)

Answer (score 1):

The design of a spring depends on the type of load it is supposed to bear. Load may be of tensile or compressive nature, apart from that it is of immense importance that the spring  does not cause  discomfort . Helical springs serve quite well as it has enough free length to contract or expand upon application of load, the force thus is transmitted softly to the other  parts causing less jerk . on the contrary, a solid cylidrical rod would not compress or elongate(much) upon application of load, causing discomfort.
helical springs find use as shock absorber in automobiles making you ride comfortable.In case of heavier carriers e.g trucks,buses.etc leaf springs are preferable.

Comment: Good answer. To add a note: Not all springs are helicoidal se this reference for a common truck/car spring http://www.google.com.br/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hoesch.com.br%2Fimages%2Finternas%2Fprodutos%2Fimg_feixes_molas.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hoesch.com.br%2Findex.php%2Fprodutos-feixes%2Ffeixes-de-molas&h=190&w=611&tbnid=geNYMnxGdTHRpM%3A&zoom=1&docid=sQmNmzK1GXAWVM&ei=OyCSU8rXHOPhsASNqID4Dw&tbm=isch&ved=0CCwQMygCMAI&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=2041&page=1&start=0&ndsp=40

Answer (score 1):

because a helical shape transforms the pulling force on the spring to a twisting force on slices of the wire that makes up the spring. Think of the helical spring as a coiled up torsion bar.

This also allows a much larger spring constant (displacement/applied force); especially for compression loads as there is somewhere for the volume to go as the spring gets compressed.

The helical shape allows for better fine-tuning of the spring as well; increasing the radius of the coils increases the spring constant, adding coils does as well, increasing the thickness of the wire making up the spring decreases the spring constant